# Why Sharepoint rest API gives irrelevant results as compared to the search in browser and why the sorting isn't same

Tags: sharepoint

I am using SharePoint rest API to query a SharePoint online site. Using the same account, when I search in browser, it gives back a set of results which isn't similar when I call using the rest API. Some data are missing while calling using API, and results are not ordered as web. What could be the reason?

Any idea around this or am I missing something here?

I tried using Properties='EnableDynamicGroups:true' and trimduplicates=false but both doesn't help.

This is the search query that I am using, SharepointSiteUrl/_api/search/query?querytext='Introduction'

The results returned from the rest API is supposed to be same as that we get when searching the site.